# Finding trustworthy financial help for my partner in the event of my death

Tags: insurance

I'm currently researching options for my partner to manage the money she'd get, in the event of my death.

In short my wife is not financially literate, but if I died would be coming into an individual term payout, a group payout, and the money accrued in my pension plan - roughly 850k. At this time we have one child, and plan to have another in a few years.

How do I find an honest and effective financial adviser? Essentially I'm hoping to minimize the likelihood that someone cheats her, or makes an unwise decision with her payout.

Comment: Both https://money.stackexchange.com/q/8460/53443 and https://money.stackexchange.com/q/16837/53443 may contain some useful answers.

Comment: You've almost certainly already considered this, but you really have to address "my wife is not financially literate" - not least because, suppose you find this ideal adviser, you pass away, and then a week later so does that adviser! What is your wife supposed to do then, without either some measure of financial literacy or at least the means to find a new ideal adviser?

Comment: @AakashM "you pass away, and then a week later so does that adviser" or retires or changes profession.

Comment: There's a higher potential for monkey business by a individual financial  adviser (churning assets, investing in high commission assets, etc.) either directly or in cahoots with their  designated broker.  Consider evaluating the trust department of a major bank.  They have a fiduciary responsibility to manage the assets prudently and will not be susceptible to "dying, retiring or changing careers".

Answer (score 1):

Is your wife interested (or could she be interested) in becoming financially literate?

If so, that's your focus. If not, then you need to arrange things to function without her intervention at your passing; arranging your affairs now with a trusted advisor so that she doesn't have to depend on advice you don't trust after you're gone.

Comment: The teaching the wife to become literate is a good suggestion, but your second paragraph is simply a restatement of what the OP is already doing by asking the question ("_How do I find an honest and effective financial adviser?_").

Comment: The intent of my suggestion that the OP "arrange his affairs now" (while he is living) was to avoid the need to find an advisor that he would trust leaving their estate with.

Comment: depending on their own expertise (and being mindful of dunning-krueger) it might not be wise to spend the money on a financial advisor before it's necessary.

Comment: @xyious, some advisors will work on an hourly basis, which would help keep the cost proportional to the need.

Answer (score -2):

It practically hard to get trusted peoples in life. Peoples can be trusted after years of knowing each other even that sometimes do not work. Money is the root of mostly all the problems on the planet. People changes for money, it can breaks families, it can break every relationship.

But we can definitely get professional peoples after due research and diligence who are true to their profession based on years of professional experience and based on reviewing their already existing clients base.

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question: "**How** do I find an honest and effective financial adviser?"